# Generate icon classes before generating CSS from SCSS code

Tags: sass, webpack-4, webpack-style-loader, sass-loader

I'm trying to create a UI library using webpack and fractal-build. Here, I am doing the following: generate Icons from SVGs / use the icon classes in SCSS code to extend it to element's class.

CSS classes being generated from SVG files and icon-classes extended in SCSS code sample example:

```
.icon-<svg-file-name>:before {
  content: '<content-id>';
  <Style attributes for icons>
}


.close {
  @extend .icon-close;
}
```

Extend is not working for me, because the icon class is not found during CSS generation from SCSS.
Please help me as how it can be achieved. Below is snapshot of my webpack config:

```
// Process CSS with PostCSS.
// https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader
POSTCSS: {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
            // Add vendor prefixes to CSS rules. https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer
            autoprefixer,
        ],
    },
},

// Compile SASS to CSS.
// https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader
SASS: {
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        sassOptions: {
            importer: globImporter(),
        },
        prependData: "$dateTimestamp: " + dateTimestamp + ";",
    },
},

// Inject CSS into the DOM.
// https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader
STYLE: {
    loader: 'style-loader',
},

// Generates fonts from SVG icons.
// https://github.com/jeerbl/webfonts-loader
WEBFONT: {
    loader: 'webfonts-loader',
},
```

AND THE CODE, WHERE THE MODULES ARE REQUESTED:

```
module: {
        // An array of rules which are matched to requests when modules are created.
        // These rules can modify how the module is created.
        // They can apply loaders to the module, or modify the parser.
        rules: [
            {
                // Parse all Javascript files.
                test: /\.js$/, // use this loader for JavaScript files
                enforce: 'pre', // this is a pre-loader, which helps reinforce that this must run before normal loaders
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.BABEL,
                ],
            },
            {
                // Parse all font files.
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|otf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.FONT],
            },
            {
                // Parse all icon font files.
                test: /\.font\.js/,
                use: [
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.MINI_CSS_EXTRACT(webpackEnv),
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.CSS,
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.SASS,
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.WEBFONT,
                ],
            },
            {
                // Parse all style files.
                test: /\.s?css$/, // use this loader for SASS & CSS files
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                use: [
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.STYLE,
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.MINI_CSS_EXTRACT(webpackEnv),
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.CSS,
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.POSTCSS,
                    WEBPACK_OPTIONS.LOADERS.SASS,
                ],
            },

        ],
    },
```

Comment: So do you have a folder containing all the svg files? Because you could have a pre-compilation step ( prior to webpack running ) that creates an _index.scss file containing all svgs? Then that file can be incorporated as already generated into the rest of your scss files.

Comment: Yes, I have a folder containing all SVG files. I am looking for similar solution and need some pointers related to webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to the above query -
I have generated .scss file using `scssFile: true` in webfonts-loader config.
So, whenever SCSS files are parsed, it's able to find the icon classes and the issue gets resolved.